# android programming auto margin as in css

Tags: android

I am very new to android programming.I have learned css and I want to make margin 0 auto like in css.This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.qwe.androidtutorial_1.Layout">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/alici"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/konu"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how my design looks like => [IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jizLa.png)

I want to design like this =>[IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62IIi.png)

I want to make this using margin 0 auto(as in css) which makes linearlayout perfectly vertically center in relativelayout.How can I make this?

Comment: change android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal" in LinearLayout

Comment: @anonymous not working

Comment: Change Your main RelativeLayout  to LinearLayout  And Set android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: or  you can use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" In LinearLayout  with no change in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

in **Main** **RelativeLayout**.

Comment: I have checked then I reply to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/alici"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/konu"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


If it is useful, please vote.
```